# update the value of the json key using HTML5 localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
var data = {  
       "mid":"10000XXX",          
       "css":{  
          "header":{  
             "background-color":"#000",
             "color":"#fff",
             "font-size":"10"
          },
          "txndescr":{  
             "background-color":"#000",
             "color":"#fff",
             "font-size":"10"
          }          
       }
    };
```

I have stored in the localstrorage in the following way,

```
// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('defaultTheme', JSON.stringify(data));
```

And i want to update the 'header' **background-color** (#000 to #FFF) property. how to update the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to update an Object already in localStorage is as follows:

1. Fetch the existing item
2. Update the value
3. Save the updated item

   ```
   //1. Fetch the existing item
   var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('defaultTheme'));
   //2. Update the value
   data.css.header['background-color'] = '#CCC';
   //3. Save the update item
   localStorage.setItem('defaultTheme', JSON.stringify(data));
   ```

Cheers